# Jenkins pipeline using docker agent can't push on artifactory due to jvm cacert

Tags: java, docker, maven, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I need to push some jar files obtained during a Jenkins pipeline, to Jfrog;
below the code:

```
stage ('Artifactory configuration') {
            when { expression { params.runDelivery } }
            steps {
                rtServer (
                    id: "artifactory",
                    url: "https://jfroglocal/artifactory",
                    credentialsId: "jfrog"
                )

                rtMavenDeployer (
                    id: "MAVEN_DEPLOYER",
                    serverId: "artifactory",
                    releaseRepo: "example-repo-local",
                    snapshotRepo: "example-repo-local"
                )
            }
        }
```

here the error:

```
[m org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli -  Skipping deployment of remaining artifacts (if any) and build info. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target etc
```

if I run the pipeline directly from the "jenkins slave server" the error disappear after linkng  /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacert to /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts

if I run the same pipeline from an docker agent the error persists; below the declared agent:

```
agent {
        docker {
            label 'Ubuntu-20.04-Slave'
            image 'node:10'
            args '-u root'
        }

    }
```

how can i link the cacert file into the container?

Comment: Hi, I am having difficulties to understand where do you specify which file (e.g .zip ) you want to deploy? Also don't you need a rtMavenRun method as well? Thanks

Comment: i want run the "stage ('Artifactory configuration') " into the agent Docker...but it seems not easy....at the moment I have used a work around changing the workspace and uploading the files using the "classic" agent...if you use a docker agent  in a pipeline, jenkins creates 2 different  workspace (one for the classic agent and one for the docker agent)

Answer (score 1):

try it with

`args '-v /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacert: /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts'`